# How do I change the background color of current week in fullcalendar http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to change the background color of the current week on load event of web browser. So everytime I see the calendar it shows the current week highlighted with any background color ONLY IN MONTH view.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried and how did/does the code look like? We need to know those things to be able to help you.

Comment: I have tried this it changes background color of the week after click but I want it to be on browser load. http://jsfiddle.net/bAhmed/kMKCn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line in your `$(document).ready` function - after the fullCalendar init:

```
$('.fc-today').siblings().addClass('week-highlight');
```

Here `fc-today` is the class that represents today. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I have tried but it didn't work, You may implement your above solution here. jsfiddle.net/bAhmed/kMKCn

Comment: It seems that you have practiced alot, I just have a quick question may be you can help I WANT TO CODE ON ARROWS BUTTONS IN WEEK VIEW. e.g i have two calendars on my page what i want is when some one changes the week from the arrow buttons it will highlight the whole week,JUST NEED TO CATCH THE SPECIFIC EVENT WHICH IS TRIGGERED SO I CAN CODE IN IT.

Comment: `viewDisplay: function(view){}` - this is triggered every time you select a different date range. Check for the view you want (like `basicWeek`).

Comment: This is no longer clearing the previous clicked week

Answer (score 1):

@ganeshk's answer has stopped working in new interation of Full Calendar. Updated answer follows for dayClick function:

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        // $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('week-highlight');
        $('.week-highlight').removeClass('week-highlight');
        $(this).parent().addClass('week-highlight');
    }
```